# How to solve Django : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djoser'

Tags: django, djoser

I have installed djoser on my Django project, however , for some reason, It will not find djoser and throw :

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djoser'"

You can see djoser is on my settings.py installed apps and it's installed on my venv, which is also activate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Order of the installed apps matter, try adding 'django.contrib.auth` as mentioned in djoser docs.

Comment: Tried changing 'djoser' to top and bottom, but didn't make much difference, so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the documentation of djoser, the documentation clearly says to add djoser after auth app and django_rest in installed apps, please follow the official  [documentation](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

If you still face the error try reinstalling the packages and follow the steps in this video [tutorial](https://asciinema.org/a/94J4eG2tSBD2iEfF30a6vGtXw)

Comment: I have done this, but my problem persists, actually I just moved 'djoser' to the top after it failed so many times, I don't understand where the problem is coming from

Comment: I have updated the answer please check the video tutorial and try following it step by step

Answer (score 0):

May be it's sufficient to accomplish djoser operation to install module by:

pip install djoser

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall djoser and install with python -m like this `python -m pip install djoser`. Sometimes it help with error `no module named`.